# Индекс находится вне границ массива C#

Tags: c#

помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Возникает в этом месте

```
textBox2.AppendText(values[1] + ";");
```

Вот сам код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog text = new OpenFileDialog();
            text.Filter = "Blablabla |*.txt";
            string file_name = "";
            if (text.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   
            {
                file_name = text.FileName;
                textBox3.Text = file_name;

                string[] x_text = File.ReadLines(file_name, Encoding.UTF8).ToArray();


                foreach (string str in x_text) 
                    {
                        string[] values = str.Split(';');

                        textBox1.AppendText(values[0] + ";");
                        textBox2.AppendText(values[1] + ";");
                    }





            }
        }

        private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult res = new DialogResult();
            res = MessageBox.Show("Вы действительно хотите выйти?",
                                             "Выход из программы",
                                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
            { Close(); }
            else
            { return; }
        }
    }
}
```

Данные загружаются в формате

```
x0;y0
x1;y1
x2;y2
```

и т.д

Comment: ну и в какой то из строк пропустили `;` или добавили перенос строки в конце файла, который тоже считывается как пустая строка

Comment: Научитесь производить отладку, поставьте чекпоинт, ну или хотя бы напишите вывод значения в консоль (прим: `Debug.WriteLine(str);`) перед строкой с ошибкой и смотрите на то, что вы все же пытаетесь разбить через `Split();`. Если вы научитесь делать даже простейшую отладку своего кода, то подобных вопросов попросту у вас не будет!

Comment: tym32167, вы были правы, действительно, в блокноте от куда-то взялась пустая строка.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, попытался посмотреть значения, находящиеся в переменных, а их там не было, на большее меня не хватило

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вы разделяете строку `str.Split(';')` по знаку `;` и тут же добавляете этот знак: `values[0] + ";"`.

Comment: Для разделения значений в textbox`ах